# Providing shared read-only ressources to parallel processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am working on a problem that allows for some rather unproblematic parallelisation.  I am having difficulties figuring out what suitable.  parallelising mechanisms are available in Python.  I am working with python 3.9 on MacOS.

My pipeline is:

- `get_common_input()` acquires some data in a way not easily parallelisable. If that matters, its return value `common_input_1` a list of list of integers.
- `parallel_computation_1()` gets the `common_input_1` and an individual input from a list `individual_inputs`. The common input is only read.
- `common_input_2` is more or less the collected outputs from parallel_computation_1()`.
- `parallel_computation_2()` then again gets `common_input_2` as read only input, plus some individual input.

I could do the following:

```
import multiprocessing
common_input_1 = None
common_input_2 = None

def parallel_computation_1(individual_input):
    return sum(1 for i in common_input_1 if i == individual_input)

def parallel_computation_2(individual_input):
    return individual_input in common_input_2

def main():
    multiprocessing.set_start_method('fork')
    global common_input_1
    global common_input_2
    common_input_1      = [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1]
    individual_inputs_1 = [0,1,2,3]
    individual_inputs_2 = [0,1,2,3,4]
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        common_input_2 = pool.map(parallel_computation_1, individual_inputs_1)
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        common_output = pool.map(parallel_computation_2, individual_inputs_2)
    print(common_output)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69926359/9484595), I use global variables to share the data.  That works if I use `set_start_method('fork')` (which works for me, but seems to be problematic on MacOS).

Note that if I remove the second `with multiprocessing.Pool()` to have just one Pool used for both parallel tasks, things won't work (the processes don't see the new value of `common_input_2`).

Apart from the fact that using global variables seems like bad coding style to me (Is it? That's just my gut feeling), the need to start a new pool doesn't please me, as it introduces some probably unnecessary overhead.

What do you think about these concerns, esp. the second one?

Are there good alternatives?  I see that I could use `multiprocessing.Array`, but since my data are a lists of lists, I would need to flatten it into a single list and use that in `parallel_computation` in some nontrivial way.  If my shared input  was even more complex, I would have to put quite some effort into wrapping this into `multiprocessing.Value` or `multiprocessing.Array`'s.

Comment: I assume you are using a multi-process approach because the computation is CPU-intensive, so the time to create a process pool should be negligible compared to that.

Comment: Regarding the global variables: they can make the code hard to follow if you have many functions that modify them (especially in large projects); in your case you're not modifying the state so it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @IonutTicus But am I right in suspecting that reading from global variables is rather slow?

Comment: It's true that accessing a global variable is slower than accessing a local variable because of their priorities but it's still negligible even if you access it thousands of times; you can create a local reference (preferably to the portion of the data you're going to use) to alleviate some of the overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define and compute `output_1` as a global variable before creating your process pool; that way each process will have access to the data; this won't result in any memory duplication because you're not changing that data (copy-on-write).

```py
_output_1 = serial_computation()


def parallel_computation(input_2):
    # here you can access _output_1
    # you must not modify it as this will result in creating new copy in the child process
    ...


def main():
    input_2 = ...
    with Pool() as pool:
        output_2 = pool.map(parallel_computation, input_2)
```

Comment: I see, this seems to work (if I use fork as start method; should've said that I work on MacOS, but so far, that works).  What do I do if I have parallel computations -> common output -> another parallel computation? I would have to assign the common output to a global variable and start a new pool, don't I? seems that I cannot reuse the same pool, b/c if the global variable is said in the master process after the pool is launched, it is copied as well.  Any possibility that allows launching a pool only once?

Comment: Thanks for your answer btw. I've reworked my question, incorporating your suggestion.